# What is the type of error in react-query MutationCache onError function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

What is the type of error in react-query MutationCache onError function in Typescript.
and how to override the type so that I can take the fullMessage from data, and use it

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    mutationCache: new MutationCache({
        onError: (error) => {
          const serverError = error as IServerError;

          toastError(serverError?.response?.data?.fullMessage);
        },
    }),
});
```

I don't want to use the

```
const serverError = error as IServerError;
```

as it feels hacky.

I can see using webstorm that there are generics I can pass to it, but I don't understand how can I pass those generics to it.

Answer (score 2):

`error` is of type `unknown` because react-query cannot know which kind of errors are produced by your query / mutation. You can `throw 5` and then `error` would be of type `number`.

If you think you know it's of type `IServerError`, then you'd need to do a type assertion. The safe thing to do would be a runtime check with a user defined type guard.

To narrow for `Error`, all you need is:

```
if (error instanceof Error) {
  // error is now of type Error
}
```

Comment: Yes but what is Error here ? 
You mean 
if(serverError?.response?.data instanceof Error)

But even so, would it remove the typescript complain?

Comment: Error is the build-in Error class. If you have a custom Error `IServerError` you'd need to write a user defined type guard (like axios does with `isAxiosError`), or use a type assertion.